# Using LabelEncoder from scikit learn, is there any way to change the way of encoding the values of a particular column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

When we are  encoding a column using LabelEncoder object is it possible for us to change the encoded values while encoding.

Eg : encoding a column with three class **['a', 'b', 'c' ]** it will be encoded as [1,2,3] but what if we want to encode it as **[2,1,3]**.

is it possible to do it with label encoder or there is some different way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot specify it when using LabelEncoder. Official Documentation is [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)

There is one thing you can do, create your own `replace_values` list and store variables in any order `[2,1,3]` and run `df.replace()`function to encode. [Offical df.replace() documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Hope it hepls!

Answer (score 0):

You should only use `LabelEncoder` for labels (i.e. the target variable).  Use `OrdinalEncoder` instead, and specify the `categories` parameter.